# A word for being efficient in wrongdoing?

Tags: single-word-requests

My question mostly stems from the existence of such word as infamous which perfectly solves the problem when you want to talk about someone being famous but in a bad way. When you want to address actions of a criminal or a terrorist saying that they were efficient in their actions sounds wrong, that's why I'm curious is there a word similar to infamous but in regards to efficiency?

Sentence example:
The perpetrator ended up being much more _____ than an average terrorist

Comment: I don't think so and I don't think it's needed.  Example (https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Nazism): "[Nazi] Germany is showing to the world how efficiently violence can be worked when it is not hampered by any hypocrisy or weakness masquerading as humanitarianism. It is also showing how hideous, terrible and terrifying it looks in its nakedness." Mahatma Gandhi in Zionism and Anti-Semitism (November 1938), as quoted in The Gandhi Reader: A Sourcebook of His Life and Writings, p. 319

Comment: A good place to start is the Help page.  Click on the dialog icon (upper right-hand corner), then click to the left of "chat."

Comment: @aparente001 Oh sorry I've already found it in tag description and removed my comment, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I suggest your Question is based on a misunderstanding - and a very important one - of *efficiency*.

Have you heard said *Once the rockets are up, who care's where they come down? That's not my department, said Wernher von Braun?*

Efficiency has nothing to do with right or wrong, nor could it ever.

Answer (score 1):

You might use **calculated**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calculated):

> planned or arranged in order to produce a particular effect

An example sentence by [Politico](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/08/14/what-i-saw-in-charlottesville-could-be-just-the-beginning-215487):

> In Charlottesville on Saturday, I witnessed a brutal, **calculated act** of terror.

In your sentence:

> The perpetrator ended up being much more **calculated** than an average terrorist.

Attribution:

[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calculated): "Calculated Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed April 27, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calculated.

[2](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/08/14/what-i-saw-in-charlottesville-could-be-just-the-beginning-215487): Gilmore, Brennan, M. Scott Mahaskey, Stephen Heuser, Derek Robertson, and Andrew Rae. "What I Saw in Charlottesville Could Be Just the Beginning." POLITICO Magazine. August 14, 2017. Accessed April 27, 2018. https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/08/14/what-i-saw-in-charlottesville-could-be-just-the-beginning-215487.